# Tera data to big query

Tags: google-bigquery, teradata, sign

How do we convert a tera data query  in big query if I need a field2 to give results as  -00000000001

Select
Sum(case(when field1=‘C’
Then field2
Else 0)
Format (-9999999999)char(11))

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(sum(if(field1='C', field2, 0)) as string Format '00000000000')
```

in case if you want to see explicit sign - use below

```
select cast(sum(if(field1='C', field2, 0)) as string Format 'S00000000000')
```

For quick test rune below

```
select cast(-1 as string Format 'S00000000000'), cast(1 as string Format 'S00000000000')
```

with output

[image]

Comment: I tried it, but I dint get negative sign in front of number not space for positive number 
Do we need to need to used any other function to get it ????

Comment: you should see negative sign if your sum is negative!! there was nothing about positive sign in your original question!  if you want to see explicit sign - use `Format 'S00000000000'` . let me know if this works for you :o)

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0):

Regexp_replace(cast (sum(if field1=‘C’, field2,0) )as string format (“S0000000000”),’[+]’,’  ‘)

Output
Field2 is populated with  negative sign for negative number and one space Infront of  positive number

This I added with the give solution for format from MIkhail.